# How to bind an image to a Button in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a default WPF button and a image, separated distance apart. 
When I hover or press the button, the button gets the standard blue or grey effect. What I want to achieve is, when I hover or press the image, I would also get the same hover and press effect on the button as if I'm hovering or pressing the button itself.

How to bind this is code behind? Can someone provide me a simple code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Image_MouseEnter() Handles YourImage.MouseEnter
    YourButton.CaptureMouse()
End Sub

Sub Image_MouseLeave() Handles YourImage.MouseLeave
    YourButton.ReleaseMouseCapture()
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm in C#. But I got the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use css instead of code behind?

```
.addButton { background: url("../images/add_buttons_b-02.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 0px; width: 100px; height: 28px; border: none; cursor: pointer; }
.addButton:hover { background: url("../images/add_buttons-02.png"); }
```

Just simply add css for the button :">

Hope this helps

Btw, you are the one who ask the same question several minutes ago, right? :">

Comment: @CopyNinja - this is C# WPF desktop application. It's not silverlight or web application. There is no CSS. FYI - it wasn't me who down vote you :P .

Comment: Haha, I didn't notice that :)) Sorry :)